# iOS app with Storyboard crashing with *'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

We have an app built using iOS 6 sdk (deployable on iOS 5) using Storyboards which crashes in iOS 5 (only) with this error:

[myApp] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'

The scene in question is a subclass of UITableViewController which contains a UITableView and an added UITextView property.

I have no idea what is invalid about this or why it works fine in iOS 6.

Any ideas?

PS:  I saw what appeared to be a loosely similar question regarding nibs and creating custom cells which suggested turning off auto-layout, but this app uses storyboards, has static cells, and auto-layout is already off.

Comment: do you happen to have any code within your table view controller? Try to first determine, what is responsible for the error. try to use empty view controller, then empty table view controller etc...

Comment: @Lukas1 `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;`  is the only custom code I have in the view controller.  I may just need to tear it down and rebuild it.

Answer (score 9):

Be sure that you don't have "Use Autolayout" enabled for that view. It will throw that error when ran on anything older then ios 6.

Comment: It is off.  I saw the other question.  I clicked on the controller and every UI element in the view (even including all the static cells) and all have the box unchecked.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest the following checklist

1. make sure autolayout checkbox is not ticked
2. in IB, goto File Inspector > Document Versioning > Deployment and make sure it is iOS 5.1 or lower, and > Development make sure it is Previous Version of XCode (XCode 4.5)
3. change the File Type from [Default - Interface Builder Cocoa Touch XIB] to any other C source code or something, then go to other file and come back and change back to [Default - Interface Builder Cocoa Touch XIB]

The 3rd checklist has saved me a number of times.. AAPL really have very lame and buggy development tools